# What indicators can I use to decide whether a power bank which I am interested in buying will appropriately regulate current and voltage?

Tags: battery-charging, over-voltage-protection, cellphone, powerbanks

Anker, one of the largest manufacturers of power banks, often [indicates in its ads](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Anker-PowerCore-Technology-High-Capacity-Compatible-Black/dp/B07S829LBX/ref=sr_1_29?keywords=power%2Bbank&qid=1683677275&refinements=p_89%3AAnker&rnid=1632651031&s=electronics&sr=1-29&th=1) that the product in question uses a specific system, [MultiProtect](https://deals.anker.com/multi-protect), to avoid stressing the phone battery which is being charged.

However, [ads for power banks from other major manufacturers](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Intenso-Portable-20000mAh-compatible-7313550-Black/dp/B084BJGB5P/ref=sr_1_27?keywords=power%2Bbank&qid=1683678536&refinements=p_89%3ABelkin%7CIntenso&rnid=1632651031&s=electronics&sr=1-27&th=1) are sometimes not as specific about what system they are using to protect the phone battery.

What indications can I look out for of whether or not a power bank has an integrated system to protect the phone battery which is being charged (eg by not overcharging it or charging it too fast)?

I am asking because in the past I had to replace my phone after its phone battery deteriorated I suspect due to repeatedly being charged too fast by a [power bank from an obscure manufacturer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08332VZPD/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

I am not from an electronics background, but if there is a good answer to this question it would be very useful information for consumers like myself.

Comment: In the interests of transparency, I posted a related question at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17864/will-an-intenso-power-bank-be-as-safe-for-my-phone-battery-as-an-anker-power-ban. However, Hardware Recommendations still in beta, and a minority of questions get any comments or answers there.

Comment: "Hardware Recommendations" is not a great descriptive name for an SE site. I couldn't find any questions on nails, hammers and chisels.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/280335)

Comment: @novice Please delete either this question or the one there.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's hidden on the other site now

Comment: Well, you really can't be sure of anything you buy. Any manufacturer can make a power bank and advertize it with various buzzwords that make you think some are better than others, even if they are actually not that good. Any device like a powerbank can have cheap components that develop a failure due to bad design or overstressing them, and it may start a fire or fry your phone. If the output voltage is too ripply or unstable or can't provide the current needed by phone, or does other funny things like periodically turn on/off, it could stress the phone too.

Answer (score 5):

Power banks don't charge phone batteries. Phones charge their own batteries using power from the power bank. A power bank doesn't need systems to protect your phone battery and that's not its job.

This "Multi Protect" thing is clearly a marketing buzzword. The [page you linked to](https://deals.anker.com/multi-protect) lists 11 specific items.

Out of the 11, a few are obviously useful. Did you ever short-circuit a power bank? Neither did I, but it could happen if you have loose coins in your pocket and they get into the USB port, and then you'll be glad if it has short-circuit protection. Ever accidentally dropped a pillow on one so it overheated? Also not that common, but over-temperature protection makes sense.

Every power bank - except maybe the cheapest chinesium - has over-discharge protection. Without this feature, it wouldn't shut off at 0%, it would keep going into negative % which destroys the battery so you can't charge it again.

Unless something is malfunctioning, there's no need for high voltage protection. Of course it doesn't hurt, but I wouldn't take it into account when purchasing. Unless by high voltage they're talking about static electricity. Every consumer product (except the cheapest chinesium) is protected from static electricity.

This current regulation and matching stuff could be some kind of AI that figures out if your phone battery should be charged slower and then forces it to charge slower by pretending the power bank has less power, but I doubt it - it's probably marketing bullshit.

Comment: Must be cheapest chinesium at the fourth link, because my old phone and cable were always covered in static electricity when using it! So you are saying MultiProtect is unlikely to offer a step-up in charging safety in the way that a USB standard such as USB PD PPS supposedly can?

Comment: (USB PD PPS is supposedly "safer, as gadgets and chargers communicate with each other over the USB cable to confirm the optimal charging power level. This handshaking approach supports voltage steps at 5V, 9V, 15V, 20V, and beyond for power outputs ranging from 0.5W to 240W... If two devices fail to communicate a suitable power rule, USB [PD] will default to the next power option." androidauthority.com/usb-power-delivery-806266/  I'd have thought that if a USB standard could make a difference to safety, then why would a feature claiming to improve power bank safety be so discredited?)

Comment: @novice I suppose they mean safer than non-USB chargers like laptop chargers. If you plug the wrong voltage traditional charger into your laptop it breaks the laptop. If it's a USB charger and a USB charging laptop then it's okay.

Comment: If the cheap power bank I had in the past was covering my cable/phone in static electricity, then I guess there's a good chance it wasn't fully conforming to the USB standard. Maybe a battery which doesn't fully conform to the USB standard can damage a phone. Is there any database of tests/certifications for electronic products which I can refer to to verify they meet the standard? There is a publicly available certification for the Intenso Q10000: intenso.de/sites/default/files/2019-01/summary_q10000.pdf But I can't find it for the Intenso XS2000, which is very cheap, and originates in China!

Comment: @novice I don't see how it could cover your cable and phone in static electricity. That is more to do with what material they are made of, and the environment, like the humidity, and what you are wearing

Comment: It was a Tozo power bank with an all-metal case, this cable https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0893BLGKV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and a OnePlus 3 phone with metal case. When my phone was being charged with the Tozo power bank and I ran my finger over the case of the phone or power bank I always got this sensation: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrovibration. I started using the power bank after damaging my phone and having it repaired, so I suppose that could have brought the metal case into contact or near-contact with the circuitry.

Comment: By the time I was sure that my phone battery was deteriorating it no longer practical to take the phone out with me without the power bank as backup. In the end I was unable to use the phone without having it charging from anything other than the power bank (which was much more powerful and faster-charging than plugging into the wall or charging from my laptop). By the end of 3 months my phone had passed from using the Tozo power bank as a useful backup into a dependency phase; in the end it was sucking up energy faster than even the power bank could give it, making it impossible to turn on.

Comment: @novice Static electricity is a quick zap and then that is the end of it. It is known that some shitty wall chargers can leak a small amount of high voltage electricity from the wall, and cause a very mild electric shock, constantly as long as it is plugged in. This can only happen if the system is plugged into the wall. I have never heard of this electrovibration thing or experienced it; it seems like it should be for physics research or maybe conspiracy theories; if real then sounds like it comes from the designed operation of the device and does not damage it so the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @novice phones sucking more and more power due to damage is also something I've never heard of before. Some reasons I do know about are more apps, newer versions of apps, and newer versions of the OS being more power-hungry. Also it is normal for the battery capacity to wear out but this does not cause it to suck energy faster, just hold less.